# Custom theme only loads changes every second start-up

Tags: themes

Using Emacs 26.3. 
I made a theme file. If I change the theme, then restart Emacs the change is not applied. I have to close Emacs a second time, and then only on the second start up does the change take effect.

`init.el`:

```
(load-theme 'foo t)
(package-install-file (expand-file-name "foo-theme.el" user-emacs-directory))
```

Within the theme:

```
  ... other stuff ...
  (custom-theme-set-faces
   'foo
        ;; DEFAULT
        `(default ((,class (:foreground "#FFFFFF" :background "#000000" :distant-foreground "#000000"))))
```

If I perform the following:

1. Comment out the `default` face in `foo-theme.el`
2. Save `foo-theme.el`
3. Close Emacs.
4. Open Emacs, open `foo-theme.el`, I see the change is still there but the face change was not applied to the default face (Emacs looks the same).
5. Close Emacs.
6. Open Emacs, and now I see that `foo-theme` has been applied correctly (default face looks as it should), and the `my-theme.el` file remains the same.

Why does it not apply correctly on the next start up of Emacs? How to fix it to load the theme correctly (maybe it is caching it somewhere)?

Comment: More testing, if I make a change, restart, the change is not applied, then if I undo the change save, restart, then the change is applied, even though it doesnt appear in the file!

Comment: Not able to reproduce - theme settings are reloaded every restart This probably points out that the issue is elsewhere.
Here is the mock theme I am using: ```lisp
;; dummy theme
;; http://emacsfodder.github.io/blog/notes-on-deftheme/
(deftheme foo) (custom-theme-set-faces 'foo '(default ((t (:foreground "#00feff" :background "black")))) '(fringe ((t (:background "#00ff00"))))) (provide-theme 'foo)
``` In addition, I think that `package-install-file` might not be necessary. `(load-theme 'foo t)` should be sufficient (assuming `custom-theme-directory` is set properly). What version of emacs are

Comment: The three lines you quote from your `init.el` are weird.  Where do they come from?  E.g. you shouldn't re-package-install every time.  And you shouldn't have Elisp files inside `user-emacs-directory` (you can put them inside a *subdirectory* of `user-emacs-directory` on the other hand).

Comment: @Stefan Those lines from `init.el` are from me! `foo-theme.el` is my own custom theme placed in my .emacs.d (part of my dot emacs git check out). Why not put .el files within `~/.emacs.d`, is that not what it is for?

Comment: Because `.emacs.d/<foo>.el` is often used by package `<foo>` to keep some internal information (like a history of use).  Always put your Elisp files in some subdirectory if you want to use `.emacs.d`, e.g. `~/.emacs.d/myfiles/<foo>.el`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My crystal ball says:

- `load-theme` loads the theme from `~/.emacs.d/elpa/foo-theme-<version>`
- then `package-install-file` takes your `~/.emacs.d/foo-theme.el` and installs it (aka copies it and compiles it) into `~/.emacs.d/elpa/foo-theme-<version>`.

So the first time you run Emacs after changing `~/.emacs.d/foo-theme` you load the "old" file (and copy the new file to the elpa location, so you'll get to see the change on the second invocation).

Comment: Your crystal ball was right. I changed the order to package-install-file then load-theme. Thanks!